# How can I add a delay between keyboard button presses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to add a "shoot" function to my game, where the player -a drone- would shoot a bullet upon pressing the space bar on the keyboard.

I've done that successfully but I also want the function to be on delay after executing it once. For example the player could press spacebar once then have to wait 2-3 seconds before being able to execute the function again. Hence my question, how could I make that work?

This is the current functional code.

**main.py**

```
    def shoot(self):
        self.get_drone_coordinates()

        x = self.drone_coordinates[0][0]
        y = self.drone_coordinates[0][1] - 20

        self.drone_bullet = Image(source="images/drone_bullet.png",
                                  pos=(x, y))

        self.add_widget(self.drone_bullet)
        self.bullets.append(self.drone_bullet)
```

**controls.py**

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    elif keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
        self.shoot()
```

I tried importing the time library and adding a time.sleep() function in the function in controls.py, but that froze the entire program.

```
import time

def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    elif keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
        self.shoot()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could using `Clock.schedule_once` be helpful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice for async events in kivy is to use `asyncio`. First at all you have to be sure your app runs from `asyncio.run()` instead of `App.run()`. To do this, you have to import asyncio and also you have to add a method to your App class. See the example below:

```
import asyncio

######## MAIN APP ######## 
class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Your  app stuff here

    async def kivyCoro(self):  #This is the method that's gonna launch your kivy app
        await self.async_run(async_lib='asyncio')
        print('Kivy async app finished...')

    # This func will start all the "tasks", in this case the only task is the kivy app
    async def base(self):
        (done, pending) = await asyncio.wait({self.kivyCoro()}, 
    return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instanceApp = ExampleApp() #You have to instanciate your App class
    asyncio.run(instanciaApp.base()) # Run in async mode
```

The code above will make your kivyApp to run as a "Task" (a task it's something that's gonna be concurrently executed). A task or coroutine can call another task within itself, so you can have another async task running during the execution of your kivyApp.

```
# Here you create a coroutine (global scope)
async def delayWithoutFreeze():
    print('Wait 3 segs...')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('3 segs elapsed...')
```

Finally you just have to call that async function as a task, to do that from your `_on_keyboard_down` function:

```
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    j = 0 #This is a counter to know if a delay task is running
    elif keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks(): #This loop checks if there's a delay already running
            if task.get_name()=='shootTask':
                j+=1
                print('Theres already {} shootTask'.format(j))
        if j==0: #If j == 0 means that no delay is running so you can press and action again
            # This is how you call the async func
            asyncio.create_task(delayWithoutFreeze(), name='shootTask') 
            self.shoot()
```

NOTE: Idk why u use `elif` instead `if` in the `_on_keyboard_down`. You only have 1 condition. no `elif` needed

For more info about coroutines and tasks:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. It doesn't put the shoot function on delay rather the functions that come after it inside the delayWithhoutFreeze function.

Comment: You're right, but thats all you need to make it work. You have to put your shoot action inside the delayWithhoutFreeze func so everytime you call _on_keyboard_down it's gonna call the shoot func... You only have to validate if it's  not running already (to avoid creating more than 1 task simultaneus). I had the same problem and thats how i solved it

Comment: Could you emphasize a little more as to how that could be done? I tried calling the shoot function in the delayWithoutFreeze() function but it doesn't work since the function is within the global scope. I've also tried moving the delayWithoutFreeze function within the same scope as the self.shoot function, I called the self.shoot function inside it then called self.delayWithoutFreeze function from the on_keyboard_down function, but that also didn't work.

Comment: I can help you, but first let me know if when you call "delayWithoutFreeze" from your shoot function, the program prints 'Wait 3 segs...' and after 3 segs it prints '3 segs elapsed...'... If that works it means that everythingis ok and I can guide you to the further steps

Comment: yes that does work

Comment: I already modified the code in my answer. Look at it.  You have to add the delay in the func "_on_keyboard_down". That should works, let me know if you got any problem

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you, and just to clarify the reason I'm using elif is because there are more conditions involved for more controls, I have WASD hooked up to the movement of said drone

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import time
def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers,cooldown==3):
  elif keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
      try:
            LastShot
      except:
            LastShot=0
      if time.time()-LastShot>=cooldown:
            self.shoot()
            LastShot=time.time()
```

Basically, it checks whether the time between the last shot and now is greater or equal to the cooldown, then records the time of the last shot.

`time.time()` doesn't sleep, so it doesn't stop your program. This makes sure that your program keeps running, even when waiting for the cooldown to finish.

Comment: using time.sleep() will froze the program

Comment: @EdherCarbajal shoot, forgot to edit that out. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I suggest to catch the case `time.time()-LastShot<cooldown` *inside* the `elif`-block. (So I suggest a nested `if`.) Otherwise the program will go through all other `elif` requests, although `'spacebar'` is never in question again.

Comment: That isn't exactly working. I'm getting an UnboundLocalError since the variable LastShot is apparently out of range of the assignment.

Comment: @Pyro It should be ok now.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the variable LastShot inside the if statement is a different variable from the one assigned in the try-except statement. So LastShot = time.time() never actually overrides the LastShot causing it to always be equal to 0
`if time.time()-LastShot>=cooldown:
            print(lastShot)
            self.shoot()
            LastShot=time.time()`

Comment: @Pyr0 try making it a `self.LastShot` instead.

Comment: I think the indentation in the code block is a bit off. I can not change it since edits have to be >=6 characters, where whitespaces don't count.